# Applying regex in a Map JS

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm

I'm trying to apply regex to a .map function and I don't really understand.

1. where do I need to put my regex to apply it.
2. how to apply it.

Thanks for the help.

That's the Regex: **(?<=^[\s"']*)(\w+)**
and I want to apply on every string in my map function.

```js
const stocks = require('./csvjson.json');
const { averageData } = require('./returnBool/averageData');

const getNamesStock = () => {
  const arrayValues = stocks.map((item) => item.Name);
  console.log(arrayValues);
};

getNamesStock();
exports.getNamesStock = getNamesStock;
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and its expected output, and explain what you mean by applying the regex.  Regular expressions can be used to test if strings conform to a given format, to find the first or all substrings that match a given format, to replace such substrings with static or dynamic alternatives, among other uses.  What is it you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

I am poking a bit in the dark here because I don't know the format of the stocks variable. It looks like it is an array of objects, where each object has a property named "Name". Also what are examples of item.Name, where you want to apply regex `(?<=^[\s"']*)(\w+)`? What are examples of desired results? Further, it looks like this is Node.js, not browser based JavaScript.

Assuming `'./csvjson.json'` is a JSON file, your code with `.map()` will not work as is because JSON is a string. You first need to convert the JSON text to a JavaScript object, then you can map through its items:

```
  try {
    let arrayStocks = JSON.parse(stocks);
    let arrayValues = stocks.map((item) => {
      return item.Name;
    });
    console.log(arrayValues);
  } catch(e) {
        console.log(e); // or other parse error handling
  }
```

This map will return an array of strings, where each string maps to the item.Name.

Now to your `(?<=^[\s"']*)(\w+)` regex. I can't say. I first need to see some sample Names, and same desired output after applying the regex, such as a replace:

```
    let arrayValues = stocks.map((item) => {
      return item.Name.replace(/(?<=^[\s"']*)(\w+)/, '$1');
    });
```

Comment: @yajorov843: Any questions? Does this fit your needs?